# sklearn: how to correlate test data to original data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the sklearn train_test_split function to split my training and testing data. After I split the data and run my classifier I need to be able to trace the feature and label values back to the original data records. How can I do this? Is there a way to include some sort of hidden id feature that is ignored by the classifier?

```
import json
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

json_data = r"""
[
    { "id": 101, "label": 1, "f1": 1, "f2":2, "f3": 3 },
    { "id": 653, "label": 0, "f1": 2, "f2":7, "f3": 8 },
    { "id": 219, "label": 0, "f1": 4, "f2":9, "f3": 2 },
    { "id": 726, "label": 1, "f1": 6, "f2":1, "f3": 0 },
    { "id": 403, "label": 0, "f1": 1, "f2":5, "f3": 4 }
]"""

data = json.loads(json_data)

feature_names = ["f1", "f2", "f3"]

labels = []
features = []
for item in data:
    temp_list = []
    labels.append(item["label"])
    for feature_name in feature_names:
        temp_list.append(item[feature_name])
    features.append(temp_list)

labels_train, labels_test, features_train, features_test = train_test_split(labels, features, test_size = .20, random_state = 99)

print labels_test
print features_test

## this will give us labels_test = [0], features_test = [[4,9,2]] which corresponds to record with id = 219
## how can I efficiently correlate the split data back to the original records without comparing feature values?
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally I store my input data in a Pandas data frame, and do my train-test split using an index; for your example you could use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
test_size=0.2

df = pd.read_json(json_data)
I = np.random.random(len(df)) > test_size

X_train = df[I][feature_names].values
X_test = df[~I][feature_names].values
y_train = df[I]['label'].values
y_test = df[~I]['label'].values
```